# Looking for open-source solutions for a knowledge sharing website

Tags: social-networking

There is a need in my workplace to setup a knowledge sharing site, a place where users

- can discuss projects they are working
- share documentation
- ask questions

I am looking for a open-source system that answers these needs, and that can be setup in a week, and requires only PHP and MySQL.

I am a Wordpress fan and developer and could easily implement such a system in Wordpress, however this system needs to be very simple to use for the technically challenged. Without customization, Wordpress users would still need to login to the "back-end" to post. I like the Stackexchange (OSQA) format, but these do not allow for file uploading out of the box.

I do not have experience with Buddy Press, would this be an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

[Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (as used on [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)) is open source, sets up in a few hours and requires only PHP and mySQL.  It is very easy for the technically challenged to use, although experienced people can make it do amazing things.  It includes file upload and revision features.

Two cautions from my experience:

- The Admin person needs to establish the site structure and maintain it
- Only 10% of the audience will use it and less than 1% will contribute

Comment: From my understanding, MediaWiki is not a great way to share and discuss. It a method of collaboratively working on documentation

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking for collaboration package rather than knowledge,
i'd say do a quick google search for "opensource collaboration"...
-- off hand there is http://twiki.org/ (probably your best bet)
you can have a look @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software
that will give you some clues....

Answer (score 0):

[knowledgeTree](http://knowledgetree.org/Main_Page) might be useful for you, probably (Bitnami has [an installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/knowledgetree) to deploy it easily.). Seems there you have a feature, "discussion threads", that might serve for the interaction you mention. For documents sharing, and security matters, seems very complete.

Comment: The last version of the open-source version of knowledgetree dates back to Dec 2009. It also dubs itself a document management system which is not what I are looking for.